# Function doesn't fully complete after $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I have a function that executes an API call then connects to an existing websocket where it retrieves a WebRTC stream and then creates a new div which displays the video within.

All of my error handlers claim that the connection was successful and that the video should be playing. the new div comes into existence and everything. 
I have tried to run it in both `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`.

It works perfectly fine in firefox.

However, in chrome, the video just isn't there. However, when I hold down the "enter" key for a few seconds when loading the page, it does work.... What is happening here ?

If anyone has any idea I have been stuck on this for hours. I really can't understand how holding down the enter key after typing in the URL should make any difference.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: In order to help you we need so see your code.

Comment: chrome restricts autoplay so try calling play() on the video element. If that succeeds read https://webrtchacks.com/autoplay-restrictions-and-webrtc/